# Kommasetzung nach unerheblich

Tags: comma

Bei folgendem Text bin ich mir nicht 100%ig sicher, ob nach dem unerheblich eine Kommasetzung notwendig ist. Meiner Meinung nach sollte ein Komma folgen.

> Hierbei ist es unerheblich für welche Zwecke die Aufgabe gemacht wird und wie viel Zeit zur Verfügung steht.

Also korrekt wäre das hier:

> Hierbei ist es unerheblich, für welche Zwecke die Aufgabe gemacht wird und wie viel Zeit zur Verfügung steht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemäß § 74 des [aktuellen amtlichen Regelwerks](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) (Regeln redigiert 2018) grenzt man Nebensätze mit Komma ab. Ein Nebensatz ist beispielsweise daran zu erkennen, dass das finite Verb am Ende steht. Es muss demnach heißen:

> Hierbei ist es unerheblich<sub>(Hauptsatz)</sub>
>   
>   **,**
>   
>   für welche Zwecke die Aufgabe gemacht wird und wie viel Zeit zur Verfügung steht.<sub>(Nebensatz)</sub>

Der Vollständigkeit halber sei darauf hingewiesen, dass es eine Ausnahme gibt, die in dem betrachteten Beispiel jedoch nicht zutrifft: Ist der Nebensatz formelhaft, so dürfen die abgrenzenden Kommas gemäß § 76 auch weggelassen werden.

Answer (score 2):

Das Komma wird gesetzt, weil ein weiterer vollständiger Satz folgt (mit neuem Subjekt und neuem Prädikat). In dieser Situation ist grundsätzlich ein Komma angebracht, ausser es werden "gleichrangige selbstständige Teilsätze durch Konjunktionen wie *und* oder *oder* verbunden" (§ 72 (1) Duden).